# NetSuite: Issue turning a quote into a sales order

Tags: netsuite

I have two business requirements that are currently conflicting with each other. I added the following logic to the client-side order creation code, to restrict who could order by invoice:

```
if (type == 'create' && nlapiGetContext().getRoleCenter() == 'CUSTOMER') {
    if(nlapiGetFieldValue('entity')){// shouldn't be here if no entity
        var hasTerms = nlapiLookupField('customer', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'), 'terms');
        var neededFormId = hasTerms ? 135 : 134;
        if (req && !req.getParameter('cf') && neededFormId != nlapiGetFieldValue('customform')) {
            nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), (type == 'create'), { cf: neededFormId });
        }
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, this has now broken the following needed use case: When I now click "Create Order" from a Quote, it creates it but with none of the items from the quote in the order any more. When I comment out the above logic , the "Create Order" button works fine. How can I get both? Can I somehow check if the order is being created as a result of an existing quote or not?

Comment: You want to force user to use specific form under some criteria and redirecting is breaking the quote to order functionality??

Comment: Correct. There are 4 use cases that all need to work: (1) new sales order from a customer with terms (2) new sales order from a customer without terms (3) turning a quote into a sales order from a customer with terms and (4) turning a quote into a sales order from a customer without terms. I need to both show the right form and have the items remain in the order for both (3) and (4). I can do what is suggested below,but I don't think that fixes it. The real issue, I think, is how do I redirect and not lose the items?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried getting the value of the 'createdfrom' field on the Page Init event?  If you are creating standalone SO, this field will be blank.

Comment: Ok, but I don't think this fully addresses my issue (because I wasn't clear!) Regardless of how someone is creating an order (directly or from a quote) I need to show the invoice form if they are allowed to invoice and the credit card form if not. The "Create Order" button can't just default to an Invoice.

Comment: Is the credit card a custom invoice form? If yes then you can use a before load user event script on the Invoice and use the 'customform' field to set the form to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Use "createdfrom" check as suggested by @rusty to avoid Quote converted SO to fall into your logic's trap.

However, you still may want to use the specific form, in that case you can write the logic in user event script to change the form.

If the purpose of the form is to ask for different fields which does not appear in the other form, you can try with a "beforeload user event script" which gives access to nlobjform and you can try changing the fields on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the checking when making the initial Quote form available to the client. Terms customers get the Terms quote form. Credit customers get a quote form that will always lead them to a Cash Sale.

Then just use Netsuite's inherent on the quote forms.

Cheers